# Templating input and output type in rust with bitvec

Tags: templates, generics, rust, bitvector

Here I have two functions in rust which convert a bitvec into an integer. They are identical except for their types, so I'd like to template over both:

1. the input types `BitVec` and `BitSlice`
2. the return type `u32` or `u64`

```
use bitvec::prelude::*; // bitvec = "0.22.3"

fn bslice_to_int(bv: &BitSlice::<Lsb0, u8>) -> u32 {
  let mut int = 0;
  for bit in bv {
    int = int << 1;
    if bit == true {
      int += 1;
    }
  }
  return int;
}

fn bv_to_int(bv: &BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>) -> u64 {
  let mut int = 0;
  for bit in bv {
    int = int << 1;
    if bit == true {
      int += 1;
    }
  }
  return int;
}

fn main() {
  let bits = bitvec![Lsb0, u8; 1,0,1,0];
  let val1 = bslice_to_int(&bits[0..2]);
  let val2 = bv_to_int(&bits);
  println!("{} {}", val1, val2); // "10 2"
}
```

I seem to have a different problem with each.

Trying 1) to make the input type generic:

```
fn bv_to_int_generic_in<T>(bv: &T) -> u64 {
  let mut int = 0;
  for bit in bv {
    int = int << 1;
    if bit == true {
      int += 1;
    }
  }
  return int;
}

fn main() {
  let bits = bitvec![Lsb0, u8; 1,0,1,0];
  let val1 = bv_to_int_generic_in::<BitSlice::<Lsb0, u8>>(&bits[0..2]);
  let val2 = bv_to_int_generic_in::<BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>>(&bits);
  println!("{} {}", val1, val2);
}
```

doesn't compile, and gives an error that the generic `T` doesn't have the `Iterator` trait implemented:

```
error[E0277]: `&T` is not an iterator
   --> src/main.rs:28:14
    |
28  |   for bit in bv {
    |              ^^ `&T` is not an iterator
    |
    = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&T`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&T`
note: required by `into_iter`
   --> /Users/jlees/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/collect.rs:234:5
    |
234 |     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Trying 2) to make the return type generic:

```
// Trying to template the output type
fn bv_to_int_generic_out<T>(bv: &BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>) -> T {
  let mut int: T = 0;
  for bit in bv {
    int = int << 1;
    if bit == true {
      int += 1;
    }
  }
  return int;
}

fn main() {
  let bits = bitvec![Lsb0, u8; 1,0,1,0];
  let val1: u32 = bv_to_int_generic_out::<u32>(&bits);
  let val2: u64 = bv_to_int_generic_out::<u64>(&bits);
  println!("{} {}", val1, val2);
}
```

also doesn't compile, and gives errors that `T` is not an `{integer}`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:55:20
   |
54 | fn bv_to_int_generic_out<T>(bv: &BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>) -> T {
   |                          - this type parameter
55 |   let mut int: T = 0;
   |                -   ^ expected type parameter `T`, found integer
   |                |
   |                expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `{integer}`

error[E0369]: no implementation for `T << {integer}`
  --> src/main.rs:57:15
   |
57 |     int = int << 1;
   |           --- ^^ - {integer}
   |           |
   |           T
   |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
54 | fn bv_to_int_generic_out<T: std::ops::Shl<Output = {integer}>>(bv: &BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>) -> T {
   |                           +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to type `T`
  --> src/main.rs:59:7
   |
59 |       int += 1;
   |       ---^^^^^
   |       |
   |       cannot use `+=` on type `T`
   |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
54 | fn bv_to_int_generic_out<T: std::ops::AddAssign>(bv: &BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>) -> T {
   |                           +++++++++++++++++++++
```

See also this gist for the above code in one place: https://gist.github.com/johnlees/49e6a7bd85b3545bba20e8670180f24a

I am new to rust, and I realise that I'm trying to write these like C++ templates which may well be the wrong approach. Any advice on the correct rust approach for making either the input or output types generic would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple macro to declare them:

```rust
use bitvec::prelude::*; // bitvec = "0.22.3"

macro_rules! bitvec_to {
    ($func_name:ident, $input_type:ty, $output_type:ty) => {
        fn $func_name(bv: &$input_type) ->  $output_type {
          let mut int = 0;
          for bit in bv {
            int = int << 1;
            if bit == true {
              int += 1;
            }
          }
          return int;
        }
    };
}

bitvec_to!(bslice_to_int, BitSlice::<Lsb0, u8>, u32);
bitvec_to!(bv_to_int, BitVec::<Lsb0, u8>, u64);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b428caa7d87a0087b9d07afd505cbc7)

Comment: Thanks for this neat solution which looks like a more sensible use of rust than what I was attempting. But, I still wonder if there's any way to use generics rather than a macro to solve this?

Comment: @johnlees, there is indeed, but it will be much more convoluted. You would have to bind your types to whatever operation you need to do (Add, Zero, BitSwift, Iterator for each of the types.. etc).

Comment: doesn't have `bitvec` a way of converting bit slices to native number types?